# Iteration as array but still accessible by a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value, for-in-loop

I'm writing my own game engine for simple 2D game and want to iterate children, but for some reason I would like to access each item by a key.

**Maybe anybody know any good solutions to my problems below?**

### Problem #1

I can't use `Object.keys and for-in`, because simple array iteration has 5x performance boost. Performance critical.

### Problem #2

I would like to add/remove children easily by passing child object to function:

`scene.add(child);
scene.remove(child);`

### Solution #1?

I can create data structure with both children **array** and **object**. Use **add/remove** methods to fill both array and object in same time. Of course in a case of changing `children` property, you will break the stuff, but it is not my case, you have to use add/remove.

### Real example

Rendering. Each shader program has children array.

```
_render(...args) {
    const [gl, scene, camera] = args;
    const { childrenByShaderProgram } = scene;
    const dt = 0;

    gl.clearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    camera.updateViewMatrix();

    scene.beforeUpdate(dt);

    Object.keys(childrenByShaderProgram).forEach(uuid => {
      const children = childrenByShaderProgram[uuid];
      const sp = children[0].shaderProgram;

      // Per shader program rendering.
      this._useShaderProgram(gl, sp);

      // Update view matrix uniform value.
      sp.updateUniform('u_v', camera.viewMatrix);

      for (let j = 0, len = children.length; j < len; j += 1) {
        const child = children[j];

        // Update attributes and uniforms values.
        scene.updateEachChild(child, dt);

        // Apply changes by binding uniforms and attributes.
        sp.bindUniforms(gl);
        sp.bindAttributes(gl);

        // tbd @andytyurin texture implementation should be here.
        gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, Math.floor(child.vertices.length / 2));
      }
    });

    scene.afterUpdate(dt);

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => this._render(...args));
  }
```

Next will be harder... `scene.js`

```
export class Scene {
  constructor() {
    this.childrenByShaderProgram = {};
  }

  add(child) {
    const { children } = child;

    if (children && children.legnth) {
      // Container object.
      for (let i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        const nestedChild = children[0];
        const nestedChildren = nestedChild.children;

        // Children recursion.
        if (nestedChildren && nestedChildren.length) {
          this.add(nestedChild);
        } else {
          this._addChild(nestedChild);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._addChild(child);
    }
  }

  remove(child) {
    const { children } = child;

    if (children && children.legnth) {
      // Container object.
      for (let i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i += 1) {
        const nestedChild = children[0];
        const nestedChildren = nestedChild.children;

        // Children recursion.
        if (nestedChildren && nestedChildren.length) {
          this.remove(nestedChild);
        } else {
          this._removeChild(nestedChild);
        }
      }
    } else {
      this._removeChild(child);
    }
  }

  _addChild(child) {
    const spUuid = child.shaderProgram.uuid;

    if (child.renderingIdx) {
      throw new Error(
        'Could not add child as it is already added to the scene'
      );
    }

    this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid] =
      this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid] || [];

    child.renderingIdx = this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid].length;
    this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid].push(child);
  }

  _removeChild(child) {
    const spUuid = child.shaderProgram.uuid;
    const { renderingIdx } = child;

    if (!renderingIdx) {
      throw new Error(
        'Could not remove child which has not been added to the scene'
      );
    }

    const shaderProgramChildren = this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid];
    const lenMinusOne = shaderProgramChildren.length - 1;

    if (renderingIdx === 0) {
      this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid] = shaderProgramChildren.slice(1);
    } else if (renderingIdx === lenMinusOne) {
      this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid] = shaderProgramChildren.slice(
        0,
        lenMinusOne
      );
    } else {
      this.childrenByShaderProgram[spUuid] = [
        ...shaderProgramChildren.slice(0, renderingIdx),
        ...shaderProgramChildren.slice(renderingIdx + 1)
      ];
    }
  }

  beforeUpdate(children, dt) {}

  updateEachChild(child, dt) {
    // Make appropriate calculations of matrices.
    child.update();
  }

  afterUpdate(children, dt) {}
}

export default Scene;
```

In example I'm using `renderingIdx` to remove child faster from array, but I don't want to keep any properties inside each of my child. So as alternative I can keep children in two variants as **key-value** and **Array**. It will give same performance while rendering and same performance of adding and removing children from/to scene.

Thank you!

Comment: I was just going to suggest maintaining a separate array of object keys but it looks like that's your first plan, I'd try that and see how it compares performance wise to for..in.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts `forEach` is slow in comparing with simple `for`. I can't use `array.entries()`, I need to use keys, not indexes. But idea to use  `object.entries()` looks like interesting, but still need to compare performance.

Comment: @IrkenInvader You are right, just an idea to go from, but honestly don't like this solutions. I already checked some compares between simple `for` and `forEach` and `Object.keys()`, but didn't against `for-in`, I will try. Thank you.

Comment: @AndyTyurin `Object.prototype.entries()` was actually removed from the specification, unfortunately. You can implement a polyfill, but it's not going to be as performant as you anticipate. All that's available is the static `Object.entries()` which creates an array of key/value pairs and is not lazy.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Well, looks like it's not far from iteration by using `Object.keys`. Btw, I will try to place some code in topic.

Comment: @Ninjaneer Sorry, I miss up why we need to convert array to object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution you came up with is the way to go. To keep track of the keys, it might be good to write a wrapper class:

```
class LookupArray {
 constructor(key, ...entries) {
  this.key = key;
  this.array = [];
  this.hash = {};
  this.push(...entries);
  }
  push(...entries) {
   for(const entry of entries) {
     this.hash[entry[this.key]] = entry;
     this.array.push(entry);
    }
   return entry.length;
  }
  get(id) {
  return this.hash[id] || this.array[id];
  }
}
```

So one can do:

```
const lookup = new LookupArray("length", "abcd", "defghi");
console.log(
  lookup.get(0), // "abcd"
  lookup.get(4), // "abcd"
);

for(const entry of lookup.array)
  console.log(entry);
```

---

But i guess you can achieve similar performance with less memory through `Object.entries` as outlined in the comments.

Comment: By the way, using a non-strictly-typed fallback (`hash[id]` where `id` is expected to be a string, and `array[id]` where `id` is expected to be an index), might prevent possible optimization of the function. Perhaps it should be split into two functions `getKey()` and `getIndex()` since calling code should never mix the two scenarios anyway.

Comment: Good idea, but how it works?
`this.hash[entry[this.key]] = entry;` Entry should be `String` because we are using `for-of` and array of strings.

Comment: Looks like it's pretty similar to Solution #1

Comment: @PatrickRoberts this is more like a proof of concept than a final version, and yes, i got notified... thanks

Comment: @AndyTyurin probably this makes the most sense with objects, but with strings it was less typing :)

Comment: @JonasW. All I was trying to do was update the second word to "solution" which had been misspelled -- I wonder if my edit didn't step on an incoming edit?  Anyway, glad you caught it

Comment: @georgeJempty ah okay, thanks :) (seems like my edit to fix that spelling mistake was joined with the initial post, therefore the diff is missleading)

Comment: Thank you guys. I wrote `AliasArray` to solve my problem. It eats more memory, but at the end works perfectly with **add/remove** and iteration. https://jsfiddle.net/t54vzbv8/